# Django: Querying to ImageField all images are being rendered

Tags: python, django, imagefield

So my problem is that when I try to query to the image url so it can be posted to its corresponding Post all the images that have been uploaded to the media folder is being rendered, even though in the admin panel it shows that each post has it's own image and they are assigned to different posts, instead all of them are being rendered together for each and every post.

The models that I have are `SellPost` which is for creating a post and `SellPostImage` is for assigning the image to the post.

`models.py`

```
class SellPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    type = models.ForeignKey(SellPostType, default=None)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=5, default=0.0)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default='automatic')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(SellPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title




class SellPostImage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(SellPost)
    pictures = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.post)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Post Images"
```

In the view I tried to create a context dict (because I'm a newbie in Django and have learned that from Tango with Django so I went with it) for the post and then the images:

`views.py`

```
def post(request, post_name_slug):

    context_dict = {}
    try:
        post = SellPost.objects.get(slug=post_name_slug)
        context_dict['post'] = post

        post_image = SellPostImage.objects.all()
        context_dict['post_image'] = post_image

    except SellPost.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return render(request, 'p.html', context_dict)
```

and here is how I tried to render them in the HTML file.

`p.html`

```
 <ul>
        {% for post in posts %}
        <li><a href="/p/{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.title }}</a> </li>
        {% for post_images in post_image %}

        <img style="width:200px; height:200px;" src="{{ post_images.pictures.url }}" />

    {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be filtering your `SellPostImage` on the corresponding post? `post_image = SellPostImage.objects.filter(post=post)`.

Comment: One thing I don't understand: you're passing a single 'post' in your `context_dict`, but in your template, you're looping over multiple posts: `{% for post in posts %}`. Somehow, your view and template are not compatible (or you're not showing all relevant information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to filter the `SellPostImage` for the retrieved post:

```
post = SellPost.objects.get(slug=post_name_slug)
context_dict['post'] = post

post_image = SellPostImage.objects.filter(post=post)
context_dict['post_image'] = post_image
```

---

But you can just as easily put that logic part directly into your template:

```
 {% for post in posts %}
    <li><a href="/p/{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.title }}</a> </li>
    {% for post_images in post.sellpostimage_set.all %}
      <img style="width:200px; height:200px;" src="{{ post_images.pictures.url }}" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

and then you can remove the SellPostImage in your views:

```
try:
    post = SellPost.objects.get(slug=post_name_slug)
    context_dict['post'] = post
except SellPost.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Comment: That raises an error `Type Error at /` Exception Value:  
'RelatedManager' object is not iterable on `{% for post_images in post.sellpostimage_set %}`

Comment: Sorry, that answer was written on-the-fly and with untested code. See the updated code (hint: use `.all`).

Answer (score 1):

In your `post` method you query for all `SellPostImage`s:

```
post_image = SellPostImage.objects.all()
```

That's why you get all images for each post.

You can filter only the images associated with a post by doing the following instead:

```
post_image = SellPostImage.objects.filter(post=post)
```

It will provide all images for that specific post.

Comment: And how would the `<img src="{{ }}">` would look like, because I tried your answer and used the same as the OP post and I still get all of the images.

Comment: How many images do you have actually associated (in the DB) with the post you're viewing?

Comment: For each post I have only one image. And in the admin panel under Post Images each post shows only one image.

Comment: Everts answer fixed it for me. Thank you for your help Oren :)